# salesforce validate 2 currency fields

Tags: validation, salesforce, currency

I have two currency fields, Tuition_Math__c, Tuition_Math_Max__c.

Need a validation on Tuition_Math_Max__c field.

if a value is entered in Tuition_Math_Max__c, and Tuition_Math__c is blank then user should be prompted a message that Tuition_Math__c cannot be blank.

and if Tuition_Math__c is not blank, then Tuition_Math_Max__c should be greater than Tuition_Math__c.

below validation rule is not working.

'AND (NOT(ISBLANK(Tuition_Math__c)),  Tuition_Math_Max__c > Tuition_Math__c)'

Answer (score 0):

2 validation rules might be best to show different error messages. If you really want you can combine them in one.

> if a value is entered in Tuition_Math_Max__c, and Tuition_Math__c is
> blank

`!ISBLANK(Tuition_Math_Max__c) && ISBLANK(Tuition_Math__c)`

If it appears to now work ok pay attention to bottom of the editor, make sure "treat blanks as blanks" is checked.

> if Tuition_Math__c is not blank, then Tuition_Math_Max__c should be
> greater than Tuition_Math__c

`!ISBLANK(Tuition_Math__c) && Tuition_Math_Max__c <= Tuition_Math__c`